# ElasticSearch: match subdocument's missing field in an array field

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to match documents that have an array field of subdocuments where at least one of those subdocuments is missing a field. In this example (obfuscated form of the actual thing), I'm looking for a jedi that has at least one lightsaber which is not lost. The problem is that `lost_date` only exists in the subdocument when it's value is set.

Given the index:

```json
PUT /jedi_index
{
    "mappings": {
        "jedi-type": {
            "properties": {
                "name": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "lightsabers": {
                    "properties": {
                        "color": {
                            "type": "text",
                            "fields": {
                                "keyword": {
                                    "type": "keyword",
                                    "ignore_above": 256
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "lost_date": {
                            "type": "date"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With example document:

```json
PUT /jedi_index/jedi-type/1
{
    "name": "Luke",
    "lightsabers": [
        {
            "color": "blue",
            "lost_date": "2020-12-23T13:46:37.194000"
        },
        {
            "color": "green"
        }
    ]
}
```

The closest search I can come up with is this. The problem is, it will only match jedi that have  no lost lightsabers.

```json
POST /jedi_index/_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must_not": [
                {
                    "exists": {
                        "field": "lightsabers.lost_date"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

***Note*** I'm trying to get this query to work with an existing schema without changing it. Also, I'm more proficient with MongoDB query syntax and believe an equivalent query in that system would be:

```js
db.jedi.find({
    lightsabers: {
        $elemMatch: {
            lost_date: {$exists: false}
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you did everything right except for a couple of things:

1. A collection of objects must be mapped as `nested` type for them to work
2. In order to query them, you need to wrap things in a `nested` query, surprisingly.

This is the correct(simplified) mapping:

```json
PUT /jedi_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "lightsabers": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "color": {
            "type": "text"
          },
          "lost_date": {
            "type": "date"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Sample document you gave:

```json
PUT /jedi_index/_doc/1
{
  "name": "Luke",
  "lightsabers": [
    {
      "color": "blue",
      "lost_date": "2020-12-23T13:46:37.194000"
    },
    {
      "color": "green"
    }
  ]
}
```

Now for the actual query, I feel I'm a little bit stuck here:

> I'm looking for a Jedi that has at least one lightsaber which is not lost.

Maybe checking that at least one `lost_date` has to exist and there must be one document where it doesn't exist makes sense? In any case - I'd say it's best to remodel your data, nested queries are expensive.

```json
POST /jedi_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "lightsabers",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must_not": [
                  {
                    "exists": {
                      "field": "lightsabers.lost_date"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "lightsabers",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "filter": [
                  {
                    "exists": {
                      "field": "lightsabers.lost_date"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @evaldas-buinauskas. That's exactly what I want the search to match.

So, just to be clear, there is no way that you see to perform this query without making `lightsabers` nested type? Right now, I do seem to be able to match data in the nested documents, but not for this specific kind of query. In order to perform my query, I would need that field to be declared as nested?

Comment: I attempted to update my example index in-place to have `lightsabers` be `nested` type, and it failed with the error: `object mapping [lightsabers] can't be changed from non-nested to nested`

I don't think this will be an option for me :(

Comment: Yes, in order to be able to query each array object individually, you need to use nested type. Taken from docs: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html

Also, how do you update your existing index?